# Google Apps Script Anonymous Permission

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Apps Script deployed as a web app with permission set to Public. This script accesses a sheet and pulls data from it(i.e. 10 rows at a time) and write it to that sheet's linked form. The sheet and form is also set to public sharing.

However when I the users to test the script, it's not loading and it's telling them something like they need Google Docs permission. I ask them to access the sheet thru the link and they appear as anonymous and not their logged in email.

Worth mentioning that these users don't have drive permission. But all permission are set to public so I'm not sure what's happening. Is there any workaround around this?

Comment: Who is the script set to execute as? If it's "the user accessing the web app", then they **must** have permission to use it. If it's set to run as you, then you need to run it (or any other function in the project), and complete the authorization flow.

Comment: How do you set  permissions for the web app? You need to go to Publish -> Deploy as web app, the select if you want the app to run under your account or user's account, and finally, select Execute as anyone, even anonymous'

Comment: My script permission is as follows: **Execute the App as:** User accessing the app. **Who has access to the app:** Anyone

Comment: The app access is set to anyone so I'm assuming the user accessing the web app have permission to use it.

Comment: Why not have it execute as you? If you're the owner of the sheet, the user doesn't need permission to write back to it.

Comment: @mcspiral you need to review authorization scopes. They do have permission to view it, but they do not have permission to write to your documents if your documents are not shared with them. Just as you do not get to read their documents unless they grant you permission to do so.